# Display IAM inline policy name given IAM role name using Boto3

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam

I can't find the method from https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html that will display the inline policy name in an IAM role.

I have the code for displaying the inline policy document but that's not what I am looking for.

Not this code but I'll need this code in the future

```
response = client.get_role_policy(
    RoleName='MyRole',
    PolicyName='MyInlinePolicy'
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

After one hour, I finally got it working. Geez!

```
response = client.list_role_policies(
    RoleName='MyRole'
)

print(response)
```